# Add order number as custom order item meta data in WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, metadata, hook-woocommerce, orders

I am trying to add the order number of a placed order to every single line item.
We are using a order split plugin(https://woocommerce.com/products/split-orders/) and a order combination plugin.

So to be able to track where the product originally came from I would like to add the order number to the line item as meta data when an order is created.

I tried some things before, like the code below, but I am getting errors when trying to place an order:

```
function action_woocommerce_new_order( $order_get_id ) { 
    $items = $order_get_id->get_items();
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        $item->update_meta_data( 'order_nummer', $order_get_id );
        $item->save_meta_data();
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'action_woocommerce_new_order', 10, 1 );
```

Can anyone help me in the right direction?

Best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I managed to make it work with the following code:

```
function print_order_line_item_meta( $items, $order ) {
   $order_number = $order->get_order_number();
   $items = $order->get_items();
   foreach ( $items as $item ) {
       $item->update_meta_data( '_org_ordernummer', $order_number );
       $item->save_meta_data();
   }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_on-hold', 'print_order_line_item_meta', 10, 2 );
```

Because all my orders are starting with the status "on-hold", I added the line item meta when the order has this status instead of adding it when the order is created. This is returning the order number instead of 0.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the right hook… Try the following instead:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'action_checkout_create_order_line_item', 10, 4 );
function action_checkout_create_order_line_item( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    $item->update_meta_data( 'order_number', $order->get_order_number() );
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should better work.

**Note:** If you want this custom order item meta data to be only visible in admin orders, use the meta key `_order_number` instead of `order_number`.

Comment: thank you, but this is giving "0" as a result. Should the action be called later?

question: so by adding "_" before meta data it makes it only visible for admin? good to know! thank you